# Excel file uses accumulating memory

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that is only 1MB but grows memory usage indefinitely (above 6GB) as it runs until it crashes.

The sheet is composed of 100 independent rows with about 300 columns each where it pulls in data from an Add-in and does excel calculations.  The excel has VBA that connects to a local Access DB to pull 10,000 ID's, which then goes through them in groups of 100 at a time, pulls in data from the add-in (using UDF's) and then goes to the next 100.

It does the following steps:
1) Pull in a list of 10,000 unique 8-character IDs from an Access DB, inserts them into Sheet2 (unused for anything else) - this part doesn't use much memory
2) In VBA - starting at the top, it loops through in blocks of 100 ID's at a time, copies them into A1:A100 positions in Sheet1 with the 300 columns of referencing UDF's and calculations to the ID in columb A for each row
3) Calculates the sheet to pull in new data from the UDF's for each column

This seems to only add to memory usage each time it is run even though the previous block of 100 ID's is gone (I did it this way since it seemed to crash if I did 10,000 all at once).  The workbook is on MANUAL calculation (hence step 3); and all objects are being set to = Nothing once done for the DB information copying.

How do I stop the memory usage from accumulating?  It seems related to the UDF's not clearing out of memory once they have been run. Is there a way to clear any cache in Excel or reset it with VBA after each block of 100 IDs?
Thanks

Comment: Hard to make any suggestions without actual code.

Comment: will it be the add-in itself that consumes more and more memory? any setting for that Add-In to limit usage? or a method to clear it's memory?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim Williams, there isn't enough info provided in the description to *actually* answer the question.  However, I would hazard a guess that it's a [VBA memory leak](http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=106). (In case you aren't familiar with Memory Leaks, [here is Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak))

I've encountered a couple of things that have caused memory increases similar to what you described:

1. As the article notes, the VBA Garbage Collecter only counts the number of references, so two items that refer to each other will stay in memory indefinitely.  To fix this, make sure you explicitly set their references to `Nothing`.
2. The other I've seen is COM objects that must be explicitly released by a `.Close` or `.Quit` method.

That being said, if you can provide even a rough pseudocode outline of the main loop of your code, that would go a long way towards helping the people on this site help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file "ActiveWorkbook.Save" after a number of iterations, it will clear the memory cache for you, and it will continue on as if you had saved, closed and reopened the file without wasting a lot of time.