# MS Access VBA, 'Orphan' Variables Keeping Excel Open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Really weird one. I simplified my code to focus in on the problem. I'm pulling a recordset out of Access and putting it into an Excel sheet. It works perfectly. I then open the Excel sheet and create an array of the data. If I set all variables to nothing and close everything out - Excel is still running in the background. If I run the code again it fails. If I run it a third time, it works. Pressing End and closing Excel will close out the phantom exel.exe. Even stranger, if I forcibly close Excel with Task Manager, my code will still fail the second time, although with a new error message, and will work the third time.

It fails on the line `allarray = ....` If i do not include this line, the phantom Excel.exe does not show up in the task manager

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(name:="Agenda", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)

Dim rsdata As Recordset
Set rsdata = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(name:="Data Call 2", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)


User = Environ("Username")
desktop = "C:\Users\" & User & "\Desktop\"
today = Format(Now(), "DD-Mmm-YYYY")

  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "Data Call 2", acFormatXLSX, desktop & "Data Call 2" & today & ".xlsx"

'create an excel object that we can control through access
Dim xlFile As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
        'Set xlFile = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set xlFile = New Excel.Application
       ' xlFile.Visible = True
        Set wb = xlFile.Workbooks.Open(desktop & "Data Call 2" & today & ".xlsx")


'find the size of the datacall sheet so we can get everything into our array dynamically
Dim bottom As Long
Dim lastcolumn As Long
    
      bottom = wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
   lastcolumn = wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2").UsedRange.Columns.Count
       ' bottom = wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2").Cells.Find("*", Range("a1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        
'actually put into an array
Dim allarray As Variant
Set allarray = Nothing
'ReDim allarray(bottom, lastcolumn)
    'allarray = rsdata.GetRows
    
        allarray = wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(bottom, lastcolumn))

    

Set User = Nothing
Set desktop = Nothing
Set today = Nothing

ReDim allarray(10)
Set allarray = Nothing
wb.Close True
        Set wb = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set rsdata = Nothing

xlFile.Quit

Set xlFile = Nothing

Exit Sub
```

Without task manager:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcvYX.png)

After closing phantom excel with task manager: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ULmu.png)

Again, without the allarray line, there is no issue.

I'm about to rebuild the whole thing with a recordset instead of the allarray built from the worksheet but I'm worried the same thing will happen when I eventually throw it into a workbook.

I've moved from frustrated to genuinely curious why this is happening.

Comment: There are a lot of answers/theories about this, but I still have not found a definitive solution. Here's some info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19778434/8422953

Comment: If you set Excel to be visible are there any dialogs preventing it from closing when you call `Quit` ?

Comment: FYI "fails with error message" is not very useful when trying to figure this out - *exactly how it fails* might be relevant...

Comment: Explicitly qualify references to Excel objects. Not just `Range("A1")` but `wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2").Range("A1")`. I expect same needed for the two Cells() references in Range(). Might want to establish and set a Worksheet object variable.

Comment: ^ Spot on. These are the culprits: `Cells(1, 1), Cells(bottom, lastcolumn)`. -- Doing `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2")` (and then using it) would make your code much cleaner.

Comment: You are opening two instances of Excel. To avoid this, use `Dim xlFile As Excel.Application` (without `New`).

Comment: I can not see the Option Explicit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement statement in your code! The ReDim statement looks suspicious to me.

Here is how you set Option Explicit by default in all your modules. 

Developer > Visual Basic > Insert > Module > Tools > Options > Require variable declaration > Tick the box > OK

Comment: Here's why images of errors are a bad idea  ...  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Welcome Chase! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow thank you! When I read previously about explicity qualifying references I thought I was doing it correctly with first establishing xlfile then referencing like this  `wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(bottom, lastcolumn))`

But I see I really needed to explicity qualify each part. Here is the revised and working edition

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data Call 2")
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = ws.Range("a1")
Set rng2 = ws.Cells(bottom, lastcolumn)

allarray = ws.Range(rng1, rng2)
```

And then of course setting all those to nothing.

Thanks a lot!